# Can we able to add a text in jsoneditor on click event?

Tags: angular, jsoneditor

I have integrated `jsoneditor` in Angular, (npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-jsoneditor).

When a button is clicked I want to add text inside the editor where the cursor is positioned.

I am using  `jsoneditor` in 'code' mode.

Comment: You can use already exisitng solution for this purpose,
https://github.com/mariohmol/ang-jsoneditor